# . htaccess - redirect to subfolder with HTTPS while hiding URL part

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I am trying to redirect an entire website to https:// while hiding part of the URL.

My root looks something like this:

```
/mywebsite
    /subfolder_1
    /subfolder_2
    /subfolder_3
    ............
```

So far I managed to hide the URL part as well as the file extensions:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder_1/*
RewriteRule (.*) /subfolder_1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I am however having problems redirecting to HTTPS while keeping the URL part hidden.

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

but it seems if I use this all the other changes will not apply, making the entire URL visible (`mywebsite.com/subfolder_1/index.php` instead of `mywebsite.com/index.php`).

Any ideas? I've been trying for some time now and it seems I am unable to find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subfolder_1/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /subfolder_1/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```